# Can I make readProcess drop the quotes?

Tags: haskell, process, io, system

I'm trying to write some code which runs `grep` externally, then analyses the output. Specifically, I want to do

```
grep <username> *.test
```

but, sadly,

```
readProcess "grep" [username, "*.test"]
```

seems to generate the command with double quotes around the arguments

```
grep "<username>" "*.test"
```

and as there is no individual file called asterisk-dot-test, `grep` barfs. There are files with `.test` extensions.

Can I persuade `readProcess` (or something similar) to issue the command I want?

Answer (score 9):

"*" is expanded not by `grep`, but by shell. You should run something like `sh -c 'grep username *.test` if you want the expansion.

A better way is to use `createProcess` with `ShellCommand` argument.

Comment: It's kind of inconvenient that `System.Process` doesn't have an equivalent of `readProcess` that does shell escaping.  It's a pretty common use case.

Comment: This was a useful clue, thanks. My workaround, which now does the job as intended, is to write the grep command in a shell script, then invoke the script using `readProcessWithExitCode`, as a null response is quite acceptable but reported as failure by grep.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably best going to [`createProcess`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-1.0.1.1/docs/System-Process.html#v%3AcreateProcess), which is the most general process creation function. Something like...

```
import System.Process
import System.IO

makeGrep username file = "grep " ++ username ++ " " ++ file

main :: IO ()
main = do
  (_, Just hOut, _, hProc) <- createProcess (
                                (shell (makeGrep "bob" "*.test"))
                                { std_out = CreatePipe }
                              )
  exitCode <- waitForProcess hProc
  output <- hGetContents hOut
  print output
```

Comment: Be careful here.  You can get badly bitten by the lazy I/O that's going on.  If you look at the code for `readProcess` in `System.Process`, you can get a good idea of what's needed to do this safely.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use `system` from [`System.Cmd`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-1.0.1.3/docs/System-Cmd.html). You're supposed to build a correct Shell command (e.g. do all the escaping) but it has the advantage that it uses the String as it's provided.

Comment: I'm not sure how I snarf the output of a command issued that way.

Comment: Hmm, I missed this requirement.